# Email configuration - DigitalOcean, CloudFlare, Postfix

Tags: postfix, cloudflare

I have a website (safirasaloes.com.br) hosted at DigitalOcean and DNS set at CloudFlare. I'm trying to receive e-mails at contato@safirasaloes.com.br with Postfix but I can't.

The big problem here is that I don't have a way of getting feedback from those systems in order to define where the problem is. So I don't know whether I made some mistake at CloudFlare, DigitalOcean firewall or Postfix configuration.

---

The ports allowed at my **DigitalOcean server** are:

- 5000 (SSH connection)
- 80   (web app)
- 443  (SSL)
- 25   (Receive E-mail)

---

My configuration at CloudFlare is:

<kbd>Type</kbd>     <kbd>Name</kbd>                      <kbd>Value</kbd>                                                                                <kbd>TTL</kbd>          <kbd>Active</kbd>

<kbd>A</kbd>           <kbd>safirasaloes.com.br</kbd><kbd>points to 104.236.43.94</kbd>                                                    <kbd>Automatic</kbd><kbd>true</kbd>

<kbd>CNAME</kbd><kbd>www</kbd>                        <kbd>is an alias of safirasaloes.com.br</kbd>                                      <kbd>Automatic</kbd><kbd>true</kbd>

<kbd>MX</kbd>        <kbd>safirasaloes.com.br</kbd><kbd>mail handled by mail.safirasaloes.com.br with priority 10</kbd><kbd>Automatic</kbd>

<kbd>AAAA</kbd>    <kbd>safirasaloes.com.br</kbd><kbd>points to 2604:a880:800:10::542:b001</kbd>                            <kbd>Automatic</kbd><kbd>true</kbd>

---

My FQDN was set at Postfix as safirasaloes.com.br and the main.cf is

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = safirasaloes.com.br
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = safirasaloes.com.br, safirasaloes, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Comment: test.com doesn't appear to be your domain name. Please edit your post.

Comment: For security reasons I prefer don't expose that information since I'm exposing what ports are open and etc.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There's no security benefit to hiding your domain name. Botnets scan every valid IP address trying to break into systems anyway.

Comment: @CristianoAlencar Refusing to provide the domain name makes it very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. The domain is safirasaloes.com.br

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the interest on helping. I've just edited the post with the real information. I'm don't have a lot of experience in setting up servers so I have some fear regarding security. Once again I apologize myself.

Comment: `mail.safirasaloes.com.br` doesn't resolve to anything. You've got a MX record pointing at a nonexistent subdomain.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I updated the post and I hope you can help. Once again I apologize myself.

Comment: Should I point it to safirasaloes.com.br to?

Comment: If that's the server that has your Postfix install, yes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! That fixed the problem.

Comment: @CristianoAlencar You're welcome. That's why we ask for the real domain. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, your issue was that `safirasaloes.com.br`'s MX records pointed to `mail.safirasaloes.com.br`, which didn't exist. The FQDNs referenced by a MX record must be resolvable for mail to be delivered.